# gnuplot fasten process with data read from a file

Tags: performance, gnuplot, calculation

OSX v10.10.5 and Gnuplot v5.0

I have a data file with three columns of numbers and I read the values that are stored inside to do some calculations. But it is time consuming!

Here is what I have so far:

```
#user defined function to read data in a file
#see stackoverflow: "Reading dataset value into a gnuplot variable (start of X series)"
at(file, row, col) = system( sprintf("awk -v row=%d -v col=%d 'NR == row {print $col}' %s", row, col, file) )
file="myFile"

do for [k=1:10] { #we read line by line and we want the ratio between column 2/1 and 3/1
f(k) = at(file,k,2)/at(file,k,1)
g(k) = at(file,k,3)/at(file,k,1)

# example of calculation: least square to find the best "i"
do for [i=1:10] {
    f1(i) = (a*i**2 + b*i + c) #function for the least square. a,b,c: floats
    g1(i) = (d*i**2 + e*i + f) #d,e,f: floats
    h(i) = sqrt( (f1(i)-f(k))**2 + (g1(i)-g(k))**2 )
    if (h(i)<hMin) {
        hMin=h(i)
                   }
    else {}
            } #end loop i
print i," ",hMin
} #end loop k
```

It works but as I said it takes time (around 2min for each k). When I do not make any calculation and only ask print f(k),g(k), it is << 1sec. I suspect then that the division could lead to too many digits and to unefficient calculation. I used round2 function to keep the n=4 first:

```
#see stackoverflow: How to use floor function in gnuplot
round(x) = x - floor(x) < 0.5 ? floor(x) : ceil(x)
round2(x, n) = round(x*10**n)*10.0**(-n)
f(k) = round2((at(file,k,2)/at(file,k,1)),4)
g(k) = round2((at(file,k,3)/at(file,k,1)),4)
```

but it did not change the required time.
Any idea about what's going on?

Comment: Gnuplot is a plotting tool and has only a very limited data processing capability. Of course, calling awk as external tool in every iteration is slow! Use any other tool to do all calculations for you (e.g. python script, octave, whatever)

Answer (score 0):

You did not post the full code (definitions for a, b, ..., f are missing).  But within the part of the code you have posted I think you can avoid calling `awk` that often. You can replace the functions `f(k)` and `g(k)` by simple variables `fk` and `gk`, because in fact they are constant within each k-iteration. There seems to be no need to recalculate them within each i-iteration.

```
#user defined function to read data in a file
#see stackoverflow: "Reading dataset value into a gnuplot variable (start of X series)"
at(file, row, col) = system( sprintf("awk -v row=%d -v col=%d 'NR == row {print $col}' %s", row, col, file) )
file="myFile"

do for [k=1:10] { #we read line by line and we want the ratio between column 2/1 and 3/1
    at1 = at(file,k,1)
    fk = at(file,k,2)/at1
    gk = at(file,k,3)/at1

    # example of calculation: least square to find the best "i"
    do for [i=1:10] {
        f1i = (a*i**2 + b*i + c) #function for the least square. a,b,c: floats
        g1i = (d*i**2 + e*i + f) #d,e,f: floats
        hi = sqrt( (f1i-fk)**2 + (g1i-gk)**2 )
        if (hi<hMin) {
            hMin=hi   
        } else {
        }
    } #end loop i 
    print i," ",hMin
} #end loop k
```

But there might be more interesting details in the missing code which inhibits this solution.

Comment: Perfect! Now I have only three calls to `awk` for each k-iteration: super rapid.

Comment: I also remove all the `k` and `i` index for `f`, `g` and `h` which are useless in this case.